# Perdida de valor de session cuando hago update

Tags: c#, visual-studio, webforms

Tengo una página web donde en el global.asax en el metodo  Session_Start asigno un código de usuario a una variable de sesion.

```
Session["usuario"] = "0001";
```

En un momento dado direcciono a una página de la web con un formulario donde cambio el código de usuario por otro

```
Session["usuario"] = "0002";
```

En esta misma pagina del formulario hay una entrada de texto donde tengo puesto un UpdatePanel. Cuando se hace postback con el Update la variable de sesion se me hace como un reset y me vuelve al estado  inicial del Global.asax con el valor "0001"

He probado guardando antes el valor en un ViewState, o creando una clase estatica para almacenar variables globales pero no se si es la mejor solución.

¿ Como puedo mantener el valor de esta variable de sesion a ser posible usando "Session" sin que me borre su valor ?

Answer (score -2):

Si estás usando UpdatePanel es mejor indicar que solo actualice cuando no refresque la página o volverá a refrescar las variables iniciales.

Por eso puedes indicar en el método Page_load:

```
if (!IsPostBack) {
    session["user"] = "0001";
}
```

Comment: Buena idea guardar en base de datos pero no es para guardar en cliente ya que es informacion sensible, ademas perderia velocidad de acceso, y para cambio de paginas entre formularios quizas fuera mejor una clase estatica con variables globales. Que teoricamente se deberia poder hacer lo mismo con Session porque esta para guardar variables entre sesiones.

Comment: Pues realmente una información sensible no debería estar por ahí suelta en la memoria jeje, pero claro no veo el código de lo que necesitas realmente. Si guardas algo en la sesión y se reinicia el servicio o demás, tendrás problemas. La memoria es un espacio de intercambio, no de origen ni destino.

Comment: Por eso quiero guardar en una variable de sesion porque son almacenadas durante un tiempo y cuando expira el tiempo  la informacion es destruida. Eso lo hago desde el servidor para mayor seguridad.

Comment: Le pregunté a la inteligencia artificial, como resolverlo, dice esto:Existen varias formas de resolver este problema. Una solución es almacenar la información de la sesión en un archivo XML y luego llamar a la información desde el archivo antes de cada postback. Esto le permitirá a la página mantener el valor de la sesión sin que se borre. También puede usar cookies para guardar la información de sesión, lo que le permitirá mantener la información entre páginas web.

Comment: Esta bien lo de la IA pero  me sale mas acuenta grabarlo en una clase estatica del servidor que en un archivo xml. Lo que no responde la IA es si es normal que en una variable con SESSION[""] se borre cuando hago un postback con el UpdatePanel

Comment: comprueba si no es un postback: protected void Page_Load()
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            Session["data"] = "0001";
        }
    }

Comment: No funciona asi. Cuando ya carga la pagina y se hace una llamada ajax con updatepanel hace un postback y es ahi cuando la variable de sesion pierde el valor este o no este dentro del  if !isPorback

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/previous-versions/aspnet/75x4ha6s(v=vs.100), ¿has probado a persistir las variables de sesión con cookies?

Comment: No, porque las cookies estan en el cliente y es una mala practica para guardar algun dato sensible

Comment: El ID de las variables de sesión por defecto se graban en el cliente. El código en el servidor sin la llamada del cliente no tiene sentido. Las variables de sesión tienen un tiempo de vida, creo que por defecto 20 minutos, además por diversos factores se puede reiniciar la sesión y por todo esto perderás el valor de la variable. Si necesitas un dato que permanezca asociado a un cliente, o lo devuelves al cliente o lo persistes, si lo que necesitas es que pasado un tiempo ese dato se pierda y se reinicie y no puedas controlarlo, ya lo tienes.